# "I am a 100% sure" or "I am 100% sure"?

Tags: sentence-usage

Both sound right to me I guess. Is any of the two grammatically wrong?

Is this a Brit vs American thing because I'm pretty sure I've heard them both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we speak, we say **a hundred percent** or **one hundred percent** sure.

It's easier to see when written out.

No, this is not a BrE or AmE thing. It's the same in both.

Comment: +1 And to add that "a" means the same thing as the "one" in "one hundred", so to say both would be redundant, and to say neither would be a mistake.

Comment: Would saying "I am hundred sure" sound unnatural to you? Is there a rule navigating this or is it just because adding an "a" makes the sentence flow better while speaking?

Comment: @Satya Yes, no a or one is a mistake.